# ZOOM Out function in MS Chart c#

Tags: c#, winforms, zooming, mschart

I have the following Winforms code:

```
void chart1_MouseWheel(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            double xMin = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
            double xMax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
            if (e.Delta < 0)
            {   //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
                //chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset();
            }

            if (e.Delta > 0)
            {
                double posXStart = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) - (xMax - xMin)/2 ;
                double posXFinish = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) + (xMax - xMin)/2;
                chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish);
            }
        }
```

The Zoom In function is working but when `e.Delta < 0`, I need the Zoom Out function based on the above code.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset(1);
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ZoomReset(1);
```

If you set the saveState to true when you are zooming, the ZoomReset(1) will go back to the last zoom state.  Or if you set the saveState to false, the ZoomReset(1) will just zoom all the way back out.  Here is my code, I do mine with the mouse click, but I'm sure you can get it working with scroll wheel:

```
    private void chart1_SelectionRangeChanged(object sender, CursorEventArgs e)
    {
        double startX, endX, startY, endY;

        if (chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionStart > chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionEnd)
        {
            startX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionEnd;
            endX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionStart;
        }
        else
        {
            startX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionStart;
            endX = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionEnd;
        }
        if (chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SelectionStart > chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SelectionEnd)
        {
            endY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SelectionStart;
            startY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SelectionEnd;
        }
        else
        {
            startY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SelectionStart;
            endY = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY.SelectionEnd;
        }

        if (startX == endX && startY == endY)
        {
            return;
        }

        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(startX, (endX - startX), DateTimeIntervalType.Auto, true);
        chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(startY, (endY - startY), DateTimeIntervalType.Auto, true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Baddack points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20713279/340045) you can use the `ZoomReset(1)` method to go back one step in the zoom history.  However, if you use `ZoomReset(0)` you can reset all zoom operations without having to turn the history saving off.

Comment: old post, but to go back to the first level of zoom, the time spent can be tremenduous, so, do it as quick as possible, like this:

while (chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.IsZoomed)
{
    chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ZoomReset(100);
} 

And dont forget to do it for all axis that you used

Comment: No need to use a loop for that. According to the [ZoomReset documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd467869.aspx), using ZoomReset(0)  resets all zooming operations.

Comment: Thank @NarcísCalvet - I've updated my answer with your suggestion.